# How to use do.call and cbind with a list of objects in a loop?

Tags: r, xts

I use `do.call` and `cbind` to assemble several xts objects into a more general container `data`. My objective is to implement a loop for adding the objects directly by their name from a vector.

Here is the original `do.call` :

```
data <- do.call(cbind, c(eapply(e, Cl),

                           list(A),
                           list(B),
                           list(C),
                           list(D)
))
```

Lists contain xts objects and `data` is also an xts object.

```
> str(A)
An ‘xts’ object on 2014-01-02/2015-05-25 containing:
  Data: num [1:360, 1] 100 98.9 98.5 98.4 98.7 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "A"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

When I define a vector with the name of the xts objects with :

```
objects <- c(

  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D"
)
```

And then try to make a loop through them, R logicaly handle the vector as characters and only the last entry is added, here `"D"`.

If I tell `list` to handle `o` as an xts object with `as.xts`, R returns an error saying there is no applicable method for as.xts on object of class character. My understanding is that `as.xts` must be used on multi-dimentional like data.frame and it is not appropriate here.

```
for (o in objects){

  data <- do.call(cbind, c(eapply(e, Cl), list(as.xts(o))))

}
```

I don't want to create new xts objects from scratch with `xts` so how can tell `list` that `o` is an object and not a string ? or should I use a completly different approach?

Comment: See `?get`. I guess that `as.xts(get(o))` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. It add the last entry, here `D` inside the container but for some reason `do.call` doesn't append the objects. Shall I need first to put all the objects in a list then `do.call` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also `mget` - 'multiple get' I assume. So you could do:

```
do.call(cbind, mget(objects) )
```

This avoids the need to have to build a dataframe step by step, which is generally a slow, inefficient way of doing things in R.

Comment: I was trying the `mget` but inside the loop.. now it works very good. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicola mention in the comment section the `get` command do the job here, by searching an object by it's name. Here is one solution in two steps : first the `do.call` `cbind` append lists of objects together, then a second `cbind` append all in `data`.

```
for (o in objects){

  s <- as.xts(get(o))
  temp <- do.call(cbind, c(list(s)))
  data <- cbind(data, temp)

}
```

Comment: `mget` would be more efficient here, and get rid of your need for a loop. See my answer